# Proving $ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos^2\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) = \frac{n}{2}$ with Euler's formula

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am working on proving some trigonometric identities and I am currently working on the following:

> For all $n \in \mathbb{N} ,  n \ge 2$ show that $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos^2\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) = \frac{n}{2}$$

I know that usually the term "for all n" might hint a proof with induction, however I have done it a little differently this time and wanted to see how far I can get with some Algebra, like so:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos^2\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) =  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\left(e^{\frac{i2k\pi}{n}} + e^{\frac{-i2k\pi}{n}}\right)^{2}}{2^2} $$ $$= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{e^{\frac{i4k\pi}{n}} + 2 + e^{\frac{-i4k\pi}{n}}}{4} = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(e^{\frac{(i4k\pi)}{n}} + 2 + e^{\frac{(-i4k\pi)}{n}}\right) $$ which further gives me $$\frac{1}{4}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{i4k\pi}{n}} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{-i4k\pi}{n}}\right) =$$

$$ \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1-(x)^{n}}{1-x} +2(n-1) + \frac{1-(y)^{n}}{1-y}\right) $$ for $x$ being $$ x = e^{\frac{i 4 \pi}{n}}$$ and $y$ being $$y = e^{\frac{-i4\pi}{n}}$$ (I apologize, somehow it won't let me format the e-forms into the fractions) and since the fractions both equal zero, I am left with $$\frac{2(n-1)}{4} = \frac{n-1}{2} $$ and now I am confused as to what I have missed to do or where I made my error which prevented me from getting to n/2 .I would be so so grateful if someone could help me double checking my proof and point me to my oversight; as well I always love to see different approaches on how to reach the result and further suggestions are always appreciated. Thank you a lot !!

**Edit: Error was found. Thanks a lot! Corrected version:**

$$ \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1-(x)^{n}}{1-x} + (2+2(n-1)) + \frac{1-(y)^{n}}{1-y}\right) $$ for $x$ being $$ x = e^{\frac{i 4 \pi}{n}}$$ and $y$ being $$y = e^{\frac{-i4\pi}{n}}$$ which then gives the desired result of $$\frac{2n}{4} = \frac{n}{2} $$

Comment: Almost everything is correct; but $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2 = 2n$

Comment: The equality fail when $n=2$; it only holds when $n>2$.

Comment: It is somewhat easier to first show that $\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \cos (4k \pi /n )=0$ for $n \ge 3$

Comment: @Tobius Oh goodness, yes; thank you so much !!! I have completely overlooked this :')

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for pointing that out ! I kept wondering why it did not really make sense when I tried to reason the base case for induction first

Comment: @Lozenges Yes, this makes a lot of sense, thank you !!

Comment: What about the cosine double angle formula?

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative we can proceed as follows using that $\cos^2 \theta = \frac12 \left(1+\cos 2\theta\right)$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos^2\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) =\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{4k\pi}{n}\right)\right)=\frac n2+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{4k\pi}{n}\right)=\frac n 2$$

indeed

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{4k\pi}{n}\right)=\Re\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{i\frac{4k\pi}{n}}\right)=\Re\left(\frac{1-e^{i4\pi}}{1-e^{i\frac{4\pi}{n}}}\right)=0$$

Comment: Super super clever !! Thank you a lot !!

Comment: @Cyberdoll111 Knowing that the sum of complex root of unity is equal to zero, the trigonometric identity used makes the identity very clear to understand. You are welcome! Bye